AutoIT tutorial, WinClose does nothing
I am working my way through the AutoIT tutorial titled "Tutorial - Notepad". The code looks like this:
Run("notepad.exe")
WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
Send("This is some text.")
WinClose("Untitled - Notepad")

The first 3 lines work as expected, but the last line, WinClose, does nothing. Please advise.
OS: Windows 11

Did you notice that Notepad uses your input to guess a name for the document (so the WindowTitle changes)? Anyway - run returns a PID, which you can use with ProcessClose to close the application (see the example for ProcessClose in the help window).

(Note: The example in your tutorial is probably a bit older. I remember times when the Notepad Title stayed "Untitled" until you actually saved the file. Microsoft changed that (I'm not sure when).

Use the code of function WinClose:
WinClose ("[class:Notepad]","Untitled or some text")


Same problem as in the question: works on old Windows versions, does not on newer versions. (Even when you don't define text to make it work, you haven't good control over which notepad gets closed)

my windows is 10,dont test it on other os.
